# Does javascript's fetch expose whe website it came from?

Tags: javascript, fetch

```
const res = await fetch(
"https://api.dexscreener.com/latest/dex/tokens/" + 0x00000000000...
```

);

can this website know that the request originated from a website in particular or it just sees the user's machine ip?

Comment: If they had no idea where the request came from what would be the point of CORS?

Comment: only IP I believe. so the server can allow requester ips to allow CORS.

Comment: @Casey i didnt ask if they do know, but which part they know, user ip or refering website?

Comment: @aaqib90 only user ip you think? So i can have multiple users doing these requests from my frontend with no problem?

Comment: @Casey just looked at your profile pic bro lol

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The browser will typically identify the origin of the request in the HTTP [Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) and [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) headers.

You can easily test this yourself by opening your browsers developer tools, entering `fetch("http://example.com/")` in the console, then checking the network tab for the request that's actually sent.

The behavior can vary by browser, but most common browsers will include these headers by default.